# java.lang.SecurityException: Resource is not accessible

Tags: java, swing, security, jtable, tablecelleditor

I'm receiving this exception when accessing the cells of a JTable.  It happens specifically when I click off the first cell and move to the second cell.  The error started appearing in Java 7 update 45.  In update 51, the error no longer appears, but the cells lock up instead.  Below is the rather long stack trace.

Since I assumed it had to do with the new security measures being added to java, I've tried to make the application compliant by signing all the jars and adding the appropriate manifest attributes.  But the issue still persists.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Resource is not accessible
at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.stringToValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.updateValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter$DefaultDocumentFilter.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$1.setValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.company.common.ui.table.MoneyCellEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent(MoneyCellEditor.java:67)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareEditor(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.editCellAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.company.app.core.InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.dispatchEvent(InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.java:120)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at com.company.app.ui.invoice.UpdateNonInventoryItemCostPanel.showDialog(UpdateNonInventoryItemCostPanel.java:235)
at com.company.app.ui.invoice.NonInventoryItemReconciliation.showItemReconciliationDialog(NonInventoryItemReconciliation.java:74)
at com.company.app.ui.invoice.ApproveInvoicePanel$8.done(ApproveInvoicePanel.java:959)
at com.company.app.util.BackgroundWorker.handleDone(BackgroundWorker.java:79)
at com.company.app.util.BackgroundWorker$SwingWorkerImpl.done(BackgroundWorker.java:118)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.company.app.core.InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.dispatchEvent(InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.java:120)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at com.company.app.ui.invoice.ApproveInvoicePanel.showDialog(ApproveInvoicePanel.java:755)
at com.company.app.ui.quotes.purchaseorder.PurchaseOrderSupplierInvoicesListPanel$3.done(PurchaseOrderSupplierInvoicesListPanel.java:195)
at com.company.app.util.BackgroundWorker.handleDone(BackgroundWorker.java:79)
at com.company.app.util.BackgroundWorker$SwingWorkerImpl.done(BackgroundWorker.java:118)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.company.app.core.InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.dispatchEvent(InactivityTrackingSystemEventQueue.java:120)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the error is coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any specific code I can post.  It's basically a JTable inside a dialog box.  I should point out that when I have the application running in my dev environment, this issue doesn't occur.  It only occurs when the application is compiled and run (it is a Java Webstart app).  That coupled with the fact that this only started with Java 7 update 45 and the behavior changed slightly with update 51 makes me believe this is a more general security issue brought about by the new stuff Oracle is putting in their Java releases.

Comment: Looks like the "value" class in a `JFormattedTextField` either isn't public or its `(String)` constructor is not public.

Comment: Thanks Tom, based on your comment I was able to track the problem down.  A custom cell editor for the table was using a custom JTextField which was using a private inner class formatter.  These things were getting built in a chain of constructors.  By pulling the formatter out into a seperate class and creating the JTextField outside of the constructor, the problem went away.